# BehaviourSubject returning old value after being updated across two sibling components

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two sibling components, one for filtering a list of videos and one for displaying the list of videos.

To help these two components communicate I have made a service. The service's code is as follows:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Video} from '../../assets/video';
import { BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

declare var window: any;

@Injectable()
export class VideoService {

  videoArray: Video[];
  private filteredVideoArray = new BehaviorSubject<Video[]>(window.videos);

  currentMessage = this.filteredVideoArray.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    this.videoArray = window.videos;
  }

  getVideos(): Video[] {
    return this.videoArray;
  }

  updateFilteredVideos(message: Video[]) {
    this.filteredVideoArray.next(message);
    console.log(this.filteredVideoArray.getValue());

  }

  getFilteredVideos(): Video[] {
    console.log(this.filteredVideoArray.getValue());
    return this.filteredVideoArray.getValue();
  }
}
```

Both components subscribe to the BehaviourSubject object using:

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.videoService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.videoArray = message);
```

}

And when updateFilteredVideos() is called it always prints the appropriate value, but when getFilteredVideos() is called it always returns the original value. Not the updated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because of Angular 4 DI nature. If you inject your service into 2 components without injecting it into parent component in  your components tree you will get 2 different instances of the service. My suggestion is in your root component constructor do:

```
constructor(private videoService: VideoService) {}
```

You don't need to do anything with this service except injecting it.
You can read more about root cause of this issue here: https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection

Comment: I've added that constructor to my app.component.ts and app.module.ts classes but it still isn't working :|

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try later today then and will return back to you. Might be a different issue..

Comment: No, sorry, you were completely right, my issue was i still had the service in the provider for both the children components. Once i removed those it worked fine. Thank you!